# Why does localstorage have to be a string?

Tags: html, local-storage, session-storage

I know when setting an item in window.localStorage or window.sessionStorage, it needs to be first converted to a string. I'm just wondering... why was it designed this way? I tried googling it but I couldn't find any articles on why; mostly what I found were articles on how to set localStorage.

Comment: The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-interface) requires that values be stored as strings. It doesn't say why, but most likely it has to do with (ease of) serialization and deserialization, although one could argue that serialization/deserialization should have been an implementation detail. Now if only this design decision were documented somewhere...

Answer (score -1):

I think you always get a string but you can save any value, you can use the developer tool console to see the log outputs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Store
    localStorage.setItem("integer", 1);
    localStorage.setItem("float", 1.5);
    localStorage.setItem("string", "Hello");
    localStorage.setItem("array", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

    //Retrieve
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("integer")==="1");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("float")==="1.5");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("string")==="Hello");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("array")==="1,2,3,4,5");
</script>
```

**outputs:**

[image]

Comment: Right but everything is converted to strings. If i try and set an object it gets converted to '[object Object]'. An array is turned into a comma seperated list as a string. Primitive data types are converted to strings. I CAN set non-strings into localStorage, but they are converted to strings. My question is.... why?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you can save a lot of work saving keys and values as string to be able to save different types of data, becuase that you can save an integer, a float, a string, an array or even a boolean or an object with the same functionality. 

Image a localStore with a: localStorage.set(Data Type)Item(...)

Javascript is a weakly typed language.